# Show PDF thumbnails in UIView of iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf, uiview, quartz-2d

I am quite new to iOS development. I am not able to create thumbnails from PDF file.

I have two UIViews in ViewController. First View has a horizontal tableView that shows name of PDF books while on selecting those books from first UIView, second UIView show thumbnails of all pages.

I am correctly implementing first UIView but is not able to show thumbnails in second UiView.I have gone through [***this link***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504834/how-to-generate-a-thumbnails-form-a-pdf-document-with-iphone-sdk)   but was not able to create thumbnails. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same problem but i solved it in this menner

Just need to use `UIWebView` inside UIView. `UIWebView` can open PDF file. so take a `UIWebView` load request on webView with url of your pdf. But make sure to set two properties like this `UserInteractionEnabled:NO` and `ScalesPageToFit:YES`

I have explained this in this code.............

```
UIView * view1 = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)] autorelease];
UIWebView * webView1 = [[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:view1.bounds] autorelease];
[webView1 setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
[webView1 setScalesPageToFit:YES];
[webView1 loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"Your PDF URL"]]];
[view1 addSubview:webView1];
[self.view addSubview:view1];
```

Hope this will help you............